# Moment of Inertia of a screw rotating on a horizontal plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Since a screw is kinematically equivalent to a cone, you can consider it like one, but I wanted to mathematically model the motion of a screw/cone as it is rotating on a plane. However, the moment of inertia about the instantaneous axis of rotation/line of contact is not at all easy to calculate since it is not parallel to any of the principal axes of a cone. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

to bring the cone to this position

[image]

rotate about the x- axis with the angle $~\alpha'=\pi-\alpha~$ where $~\alpha=\arctan(h/r)~$

the rotation matrix is:

$$\mathbf S_x=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\  0&\cos \left( 
\alpha' \right) &-\sin \left( \alpha' \right) \\  0&
\sin \left( \alpha' \right) &\cos \left( \alpha' \right) \end {array}
 \right]$$

The inertia  tensor (x,y,z) system is

$$\mathbf I_{xyz}= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} {\it Ix}&0&0\\  0&{\it Iy
}&0\\  0&0&{\it Iz}\end {array} \right]\\
Ix=1/20\,M \left( 3\,{r}^{2}+2\,{h}^{2} \right)\\
Iy=Ix\\
Iz=3/10\,M{r}^{2} 
$$

and the inertia tensor at the final position

$$\mathbf I_f=\mathbf S_x\,\mathbf I_{xyz}\,\mathbf S_x^T$$